# NHibernate Session Management & Castle in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have got a windows service which looks for a certain file and save it to the DB. I'm using the repository pattern and using Castle Windsor for DI.

This is how I register the NHibernate ISession and my unit of work.

```
 container.Register(
            Component.For<ISession>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession()).LifeStyle.Transient);

            container.Register(
                Component.For<INHibernateSessionManager>().Instance(NHibernateSessionManager.Instance).LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(
                Component.For<IUnitOfWork<ISession>>().ImplementedBy<Data.Framework.Nhibernate.UnitOfWork.NHibernateUnitOfWork>().LifeStyle.Transient);

            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>)).LifeStyle.Transient);
```

This does not work for me, as when it tried to resolve the repository it's complaining about a key added to the repository already.

Can you please tell me how to do this properly?

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Castle Windsor is normally pretty helpful with the exception messages it produces. Please provide the full details of the exception.